# Retrieve and update CSS value after pageload

Tags: jquery, css, pageload

I feel like this deserves a straightforward answer, but I have not been able to find it, so I apologize if I have overlooked or have been unable to find any previous answers.

**What I'm trying to accomplish:** update an element's height relative to its fluid width.

**What I have tried to do** is grab the element's width, multiply it by my desired ratio to come up with the correct height for the element. I pass this to both `(window).load` and `(window).resize` so that the height is calculated after the page loads and as the window and element width changes (the elment has 100% width) the height of that element recalculates.

Here is my code:

```
var fn = ( function() {

    var player = $( '.rem_video_wrapper iframe[style]' ),
        w = player.css('width').slice(0,-2), // strip 'px'
        h = w * 0.6;

    player.css( 'height', h );

    // the following is for updating a <p> with current values
    // for troubleshooting purposes.
    var paragraph = $( '#var' );
    paragraph.text( w + ' (' + h + ')' );

});

$( window ).load( fn );
$( window ).resize( fn );
```

**The problem** I am running into is that when the page loads, `w` seems to have no initial value, so the element's height is not set to what it should be. **However**, when I resize the page it kicks in and the element begins to behave correctly.

**How do I get my function to correctly fire after my page has completely loaded?** I'm assuming my script is trying to run before it can even correctly get the target element's width.

I have tried `$(document).ready(fn)` and that doesn't work either.

I have only recently been throwing myself into jQuery, so I am comlpetely open to the possibility that I am either going about my code the entirely wrong way, or I may be asking the wrong question to begin with. Please enlighten me!

Thank you

**EDIT:**

Here is my relevant markup.

Note: This markup is generated by [Embedder](https://github.com/A-P/Embedder) (Craft CMS plugin) and [reEmbed](https://www.reembed.com/) by using the following line in my Craft CMS template file: `{{ craft.embedder.embed (entry.youtube) }}` where `youtube` is a field containing the url for the desired YouTube playlist.

```
<div id="rem_playlist0" class="rem_playlist rem_inline_list rem_playlist_default" style="width: 459px; height: 399px;">

    <div class="rem_playlist_toolbar" style="display: block;">
        <span class="rem_playlist_title"></span>
        <span class="rem_playlist_actions">
            <span class="rem_playlist_skip_control previous disabled"></span>
            <span class="rem_playlist_info">
                <span class="rem_playlist_current">1</span>
                <span class="rem_playlist_divider">/</span>
                <span class="rem_playlist_total">27</span>
            </span>
            <span class="rem_playlist_skip_control next"></span>
            <a class="rem_toggle_inline_playlist" href="#">PLAYLIST</a>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="rem_video_wrapper">
        <iframe style="position: relative; width: 459px; height: 275.4px;" src="" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" data-rem-id="0"></iframe>
    </div>

    <ul class="rem_playlist_ul" style="margin-top: 25px; z-index: 10; display: none;">
        <li class="rem_playlist_list-item">"playlist item ..."</li>
        <li class="rem_playlist_list-item">"playlist item ..."</li>
        <li class="rem_playlist_list-item">"playlist item ..."</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML markup?

Comment: Rather than using `player.css('width').slice(0,-2)` try `player.width()` and `player.hight(h)` rather then `player.css( 'height', h )`

Comment: @Todd, `player.width()` returns `null`. It does update after you resize the window, but its initial value after pageload is `null`.

Comment: @JoseRojas I have updated my question with my markup.

Comment: Maybe try `player = $( '.rem_video_wrapper > iframe' )` as your selector rather then `player = $( '.rem_video_wrapper iframe[style]' )`

Comment: A couple of thoughts. First, is your script code in its own file and are you loading that file at the top of your markup or bottom? Second, I would think wrapping the script code in $(document).ready() would work. As you are more than likely aware, the code will not execute until the document is fully loaded.

Comment: Hey it may also be that you are using inline styling on your iframe. Maybe remove the inline styling  and place it in a CSS stylesheet. That may stop it being null on first execution.

Comment: @PaulStoner: This JS file is pulled into a single scripts.js file via Gulp. Maybe there's a conflict there? This scripts.js file is loaded at the bottom of the markup. Also, I have tried wrapping it inside `(document).ready` which has no effect. Gist here: https://gist.github.com/swthate/5aabf80828dd5993971bd82a70a8b0aa

Comment: @Todd: I tried your suggestion of `.rem_video_wrapper > iframe` but that has the same behavior. The inline style on the iframe is generated. The best I can do is to try overwriting it with CSS, eg: `.rem_video_wrapper iframe[style] { width:100% !important; height:auto !important; }`. Ugly I know, but I don't know what else to do.

Comment: @swthate: I see what you are attempting to do. Apologies. You have reached my limit. While I feel I'm rather proficient with JavaScript, when it comes to Gulp and other such items, I'm too new to know any more. Mostly I work in Visual Studio and have recently moved out and tried learning all these other frameworks.

Comment: @PaulStoner thanks for the help so far! To satisfy my own curiosity I commented out all the contents of my other JS files that are concatenated via Gulp so that only this JS file we are looking at right now is active, and I'm experiencing the same behavior. :(

Comment: Okay so you can get rid of the inline styling with `$('.rem_video_wrapper > iframe').removeAttr('style');` at the beginning of your *fn* function. Then use the CSS `.rem_video_wrapper iframe {display:block; width:100%; height:auto; }` so that `player.width()` is not *null*. That may help you.

Comment: Ugh. I was really hopeful about that one. But it isn't removing any attributes! `style` or otherwise!

Comment: I think this is what you want? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ToddNewent/pmc112n9/)

Comment: what do you think? Is this the right kind of thing?

Comment: Well it works great in JSFiddle, which is awesome. I'm still having some trouble getting it to work on my end. There must be some odd bits interfering somewhere. Still looking into it. But thanks for all the help so far! Much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe defer your scripts.js?  `<script src="scripts.js" defer></script>` as an example. Beyond that I am not too sure though I will keep thinking about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this issue by removing the inline styling of your iframe. This will allow you to retrieve the height and width and set them dynamically with the function you have created.

Try this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ToddNewent/pmc112n9/)

JQuery

```
// A function to rezise the height of <iframe> based on its width
function sizeIt() {
  var player = $('.rem_video_wrapper > iframe'),
  w = player.width(),
  h = w * 0.6;

  player.height(h);
}

//Remove inline styling and call sizeIt() for inital sizing
$(function (){
    $('.rem_video_wrapper > iframe').removeAttr('style');
    sizeIt();
});

//call sizeIt() on page resize
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  sizeIt();
});
```

Comment: While I was not able to get it to work, I simplified everything by getting rid of reEmbed and the Embedder plugin and embedding the playlist straight into the template with the code provided by YouTube. It bugs me that I can't find out what exactly was getting in the way of this working.

In any event -- thank you so much for your time and your help. I'd be interested in any ideas you may come up with if anything hits you :)

Comment: Honestly glad to help. It is a shame we could not work out why this plugins integration was skewing things, though in all maybe using YouTube's iframe directly is actually a cleaner and better approach. Good luck with the jQuery studies!